# Expressing If then else via Logical && and ||

Tags: shell, if-statement, ksh, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I am trying to  establish the equivalence of using Logical && and || operators to an 'If then else fi' condition  and I wanted to verify if that understanding's correct.
Consider this if condition , relevant to mine

```
if ( flag="$value" ) then 
function1 ( p1) 
rc=$?
    if ( "$rc"=0 ) then 
    function2 ( p2)
    fi
elif (flag="$value2" ) then
function1 ( p1) 
rc=$?
    if ( "$rc"=0 ) then 
    function2 ( p2)
    fi
else 
echo "Msg"
fi
```

written in terms of logical && and || as

```
 ( ( [ flag = "$value" ] && function1 (p1) ) && function2 (p2) ) || 
   ( ( [ flag = "$value2" ] && function1 (p2) ) && function2 (p2)) || 
    echo "message"
```

My Q's are :

- Can the above approach always be used. What  are the caveats and things to "watch out" for
- There was some talk elsewhere of () brackets spinning of a new shell whose variables are'nt available to the parent.  I wanted to see how I can  group these operators to indicate precedence, if its not those () brackets.

@Chepner. Thx for the clarification.
So in a case statement that looks like this

```
optf=false
opte=false
optp=false

case $opt in

  p ) ...
     (( $opte || $optf ) && [ -n "$s1" ] ) && echo "error message"
```

The above can be rewritten as

```
 {{ $opte || $optf } ; && [ -n "$s1" ] ; } && echo "error message"
```

and  it would translate this logic thus : when you encounter  the p option , check if opte or optf are true. If either is true and there is a value for s1 , then throw in the error message. 
Would that be the case , or there are still some holes to be plugged.
Gotcha- I was unmindful of the ";" . With { } ; - I should be able to club my  operators , way I want ?

Comment: Please start with valid shell. Your `if...else` statement is not.

Comment: `(` and `)` must be place around an entire command. They typically cause a syntax error when present as command arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that

```
if command1; then
    command2
else
    command3
fi
```

is not equivalent to `command1 && command2 || command3`.

- If `command1` fails, `command2` is skipped and `command3` runs, as expected.
- If `command1` succeeds, and `command2` runs *and succeeds*, `command3` is skipped, as expected.
- If `command1` succeeds, and `command2` runs *and fails*, `command3` is run, which differs from the `if` statement.

You would need to use something like:

```
command1 && { command2; true; } || command3
```

which would force the right-hand operand to `&&` to succeed, regardless of the success of `command2`, so that `command3` is never run when `command1` succeeds.

Comment: Thx. Can you also pl add a note on the effect of () brackets being used to direct operator precedence as against their effect in spawning new shell whose variables are not available.

Comment: You can use `{...}` for the same effect without spawning a subshell. Any changes to a variable inside `()` are not preserved outside the subshell, while change inside `{}` are.

Comment: I updated the question with a clarification. Just checking if above would be correct. Thx 'gain